# Simulate if-in statement in Java

Tags: java, python, if-statement

I've coded for several months in Python, and now i have to switch to Java for work's related reasons. My question is, there is a way to simulate this kind of statement

```
if var_name in list_name:
    # do something
```

without defining an additional `isIn()`-like boolean function that scans `list_name` in order to find `var_name`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [`List#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) which is inherited from [`Collection#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) (so you can use it with `Set` objects also)

```
if (listName.contains(varName)) {
    // doSomething
}
```

---

### `List#contains`

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : **o.equals(e)**).

As you see, `List#contains` uses `equals` to return true or false. It is strongly recommended to `@Override` this method in the classes you're creating, along with `hashcode`.

- [Why do I need to override the equals and hashcode methods in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: If the collections is more than a few elements, a more efficient alternative might be to use a Set instead of a List but then you would use Set.contains. + 1

Comment: it's important to implement equals if List is using any custom object

Comment: Thank you! @GauravaAgarwal what do you mean?

Comment: @GauravaAgarwal, yes, it is. And every time you override `equals()` you should override `hashCode()` as well to make your class hash-based collections compatible. See J. Bloch's "Effective Java" 2nd edition, Item 9

Answer (score 3):

You can use List.contains(object), but make sure your class which you have used to create list, is implementing equals for proper equals check. Otherwise you will be able to only get two objects equal only if object itself is same.

Answer (score 2):

The java.util.ArrayList.contains(Object) method returns true if this list contains the specified element.

```
List list=new ArrayList();
list.add(1);
list.add(2); 
if(list.contains(2)){
//do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the contains method of the list data structure is what you're after. You can use this in 1 of two ways:

```
boolean return_flag = list_name.contains(var_name)
if return_flag{
    //do stuff
}
```

or

```
if list_name.contains(var_name){
   //do stuff
}
```

as in Yasin's answer.

For further info refer to either 
[tutorial point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_contains.htm)
or the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))